# Interface shows data when output to the console, but getting undefined when accessing

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. I have an object that will be used to feed a vuetify data table. This object had nested objects full of data as well. I've been trying for a while to get the table to show my nested data objects, particularly on of type/interface IOrderDetails, to no avail.

I then figured I should just flatten the object. I made it so that my object took in the interface and mapped it to its members, and each member is responsible for mapping itself if it implements an interface. So I restructured

```js
class OrderDetails implements IOrderDetailsData {
    OrderId: string;
    OrderDateTime: string;
    CustomerName?: string;

    constructor(orderDetailsData: IOrderDetailsData) {
        //all these properties are undefined???
        this.OrderId = orderDetailsData.OrderId;
        this.OrderDateTime = orderDetailsData.OrderDateTime;
        this.CustomerName = orderDetailsData.CustomerName ?? "Customer"
    }
}
```

The console shows IOrderDetails as undefined, no matter what/when. But when I push whole object to the console (it's nested in a parent object), it shows the correct data. And I'm inspecting it before I try to access it. What am I not understanding about interfaces. Note that the other members are able to map themselves just fine. I cannot figure why this one is different. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I tried mapping the data from interface land to object land. I keep running into the "undefined" interface.

Data is being dispatched using Omnibus.js. So I tried awaiting the dispatch call (in this case called "trigger"). I wasn't doing that before, but I still get the same problem. Inspecting IOrderDetails before I dispatch it shows undefined. But inspecting the whole object shows IOrderDetails with data.

Comment: Please don't send code or error as image.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wanted to show the console output. I'll try to change it

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more digging around. I started converting my interfaces over to simple types, since there was no need to have them be interfaces (that's just how I got them from [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/). After debugging I noticed that the console kept showing data as OrderDetailsData, which is what I called the dto. That , however, was not the name of the property in the type (name is OrderDetails).

I looked at the json-to-property-to-type mapper you get from [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/). Turns out I wasn't mapping the data to my property, I was instead mapping it to "OrderDetailsData", (forgot to update this part when I did a refactor). Which is not a property in the parent object, so because of dynamism, I'm guessing it created the property and stuffed the data in there, instead of my property I had declared in the type. Then when trying access *my* property (thanks to Typescript), it was undefined. Cool.

In summary, the answer to my issue is ->
Don't be bad at programming.